# Add attribute in model classes by user in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

On my store site, in the product features section, the user must add these features himself. Even new categories can be added to it. And the important thing is that each product has its own unique features. For example, a mobile phone has a feature of camera information, a dress has a feature of the material used, etc. It would be useless if I write these myself and make a separate class for each class. That's why I want my user to do this in a personalized way. It means adding more fields and attributes to the class by the user through his user panel. What is the solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Share your code that is already developed and related to the problem, otherwise noone can actually help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.